# How to "save" my wordpress blog's posts in same url format and remove wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog running on my site and I have no time to continuously upgrade the software and I pretty much want to remove wordpress. It's broken at this point anyway, I can't really get into the admin area, but I suppose I could try to hack my way through.

Anyway, I'd like to save the posts that I have and keep them under the same URL structure so they're still relevant in the search results indexes.

Here's the site in question: http://www.danielfischer.com

Any suggestions on how to keep the site up but possibly turn it static yet keep the same url structure? A static archive of what used to be and have the urls still work pretty much?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like someone was playing around with the theme files and left some whitespace in functions.php. You're lucky that it only brings down the admin; normally this affects the whole site. If you can FTP into your site, I'd look into fixing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mirroring tool like [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) to download the entire site to individual HTML files. HTT shouldn't have any problem making folders from the URL structure (though if there are any non-pretty URLs linked, it'll grab those too).

From there, just upload those files and call it an archive (maybe put them in a separate directory & point the server to it so Wordpress doesn't get totally wiped out, just in case).

Answer (score 1):

Switch on WP-Cache or better yet, install [WP-Super-Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache). Make sure it caches every page you have (set the cache timeout to never in settings). This will create static versions of every page within the cache folder. Once you have all pages cached, go into the cache folder (`/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{HTTP_HOST}/` by default, where HTTP_HOST is your host name) and copy all of those files and folders into a new webroot (create a new site with whatever the hosting panel is you are using, or in apache manually). Switch your domain over to this new webroot and if everything is working, delete wordpress.

A good shortcut would be to setup a site (such as test.yourblogname.com) and point the sites directory straight into the cache directory (ie. point it to `/wp-content/cache/supercache/hostname/`). That way you can test it without risking anything.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a help for you 
http://www.setuptips.com/wordpress/recovering-a-broken-wordpress-blog-without-a-backup-copy/